# Internet Explorer 6 under windows 10

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

I am using windows 10. I have some tutorials which requires to run on internet explorer 6.0 + .

when i try to run those tutorials it runs on Microsoft Edge. after a spash screen it shows the message that it requires IE 6.0 +.

Is there any way to download and install IE 6.0 + on win10. 
or Is there any to make Microsoft Edge behave like IE 6.0

Thanks.
- Shahid

Comment: It is not possible to run any other version of IE except IE11 on Windows 10.  If you literally need IE6 run it within a virtual machine, Microsoft provides free virtual machines, for exactly this purpose.

Comment: My answer in the above link covers IE6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate IE6 in Edge. While in Edge, press F12 key. You will get a popout window. Go to the "Emulation" tab and change the "User Agent String" to Internet Explorer 6. Refresh your site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have navigated as you say. I have found till IE 8.0 along with other option. But Not found IE 6.0 // I have tried to run my application with IE 8. but it is not running on IE 8.0 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The message probably doesn't know what Edge is.

1. Click the 3 dots in the top right
2. click 'open in Internet
   Explorer'

It should then load correctly.

Comment: That will not run IE6.

Comment: It is requesting 6+ so it should work. It is seeing edge as an unknown entity.